# libgdx setUserObject() not setting Object

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to resort a SnapShotArray so I may render my actors in the correct order.  Ordering should be an absolute distance from a center, though I want to hold on to sign for later in the rendering process to determine whether it put to the left or right of center.  I determined distance from center for each actor in the first for loop, and tried using setUserObject().  When I later tried to retrieve this in the sort Comparator I was told it was a null value.

```
SnapshotArray<Actor> children = getChildren();
    children.begin();
    int n = children.size;
    
    for (int i = getIndexOfFocus() + 1; i < n; i++) {
        Actor child = children.get(i);
        int offset = i - Math.round(getIndexOfFocus());
        child.setUserObject(Integer.valueOf(offset));
    }
    //Arrays.sort(<SnapShotArray>children, 0, n, new MyElementComparator());
    children.sort(new MyElementComparator());
```

Comparator class:

```
private static class MyElementComparator implements Comparator<Actor>{
       public int compare (Actor a1, Actor a2){
           Integer e1 = (Integer) a1.getUserObject();
           Integer e2 = (Integer) a2.getUserObject();
           System.out.println("1(" + a1 + ", " + e1 + "), 2(" + a2 + ", " + e2 + ")");
           int r = 0;
           if (Math.abs(e1) < Math.abs(e2)) r = -1;
           if (Math.abs(e1) == Math.abs(e2)) r = 0;
           if (Math.abs(e1) > Math.abs(e2)) r = 1;
           return r;
       }
    }
```

results of Sys out above:

```
    1(TextButton: index_1, null), 2(TextButton: index_0, null)
```

Comment: You're only setting the user object on a subset of the array. Your `i` in the for loop doesn't start at 0.

Comment: Arg!  I'm filled with self-loathing for missing that.  Luckily it's balanced out by how cool it is to have a working program.